# Delphi graphics32 saving layers as transparent PNG goes wrong

Tags: delphi, graphics32

I am having a strange problem, and I do not think I can solve it.
I have an ImgView containing layers (transparent png images) and I intend to save all the layers as png files (like a "Save Project" thing), so that later on I can re-open them and place them where I left them. (like an "Open Project" thing)
This is my problem, following steps work just fine:

1. I add layers (transparent PNG files)
2. I move them around and place them where I want them
3. I press save project (so here I save all layers as png image files)
4. It works

If I do the next following steps, something goes wrong:

1. I add layers (transparent PNG files)
2. I move them around and place them where I want them
3. I change the location of the layers (as in: send to back one layer for example) **(so this step is different)**
4. I press save project (so here I save all layers as png image files)
5. It crashes with "Access violation at address 005380FB in module 'MyApp.exe'. Read of address 000000C0"

Right now it only gives me the above error, but a few runs ago, it pointed me to this line:

```
procedure TCustomBitmap32.ResetAlpha(const AlphaValue: Byte);
var
  I: Integer;
  P: PByteArray;
begin
  if not FMeasuringMode then  <<<<<------ this line
```

So if I change the index of layers... I cannot save them anymore as PNG ?!?!?!

Here is my save procedure:

```
  for i:=0 to mainForm.ImgView.Layers.Count-2 do
  begin
    mylay := TBitmapLayer(mainForm.ImgView.Layers.Items[i]);
    SaveBMPAsPng(mylay.Bitmap,'C:\MyApp\tmp\'+getLayerPan(i)+'.png');
  end;
// where getLayerPan is a function that retrieves a name that I gave to the layer
```

...  and

```
procedure SaveBmpAsPng(bmp:TBitmap32;dest:string);
var
  Y: Integer;
  X: Integer;
  Png: TPortableNetworkGraphic32;

  function IsWhite(Color32: TColor32): Boolean;
  begin
    Result:= (TColor32Entry(Color32).B = 255) and
             (TColor32Entry(Color32).G = 255) and
             (TColor32Entry(Color32).R = 255);
  end;

begin
    bmp.ResetAlpha;
    for Y := 0 to bmp.Height-1 do
      for X := 0 to bmp.Width-1 do
      begin
        if IsWhite(bmp.Pixel[X, Y]) then
          bmp.Pixel[X,Y]:=Color32(255,255,255,0);
      end;
    Png:= TPortableNetworkGraphic32.Create;
    Png.Assign(bmp);
    Png.SaveToFile(dest);
    Png.Free;
end;
```

What could be wrong?
Please help...

**EDIT**
I think I discovered my problem... 
When I move the layers around, the only way (that I know of) to do it clean, is to load all layers into an imagelist (TBitmap32List was my choice at that moment) and after that clean the layers and re-add them from the imagelist to my ImageView in the desired order.
I can only assume that this is where something goes wrong.
It must be because in the layers I have transparent PNGs, and when I load them into the Bitmap32List, I load them as BMPs.
I must look for another way of reorganizing my layers before going any further. I will update you with my solution. If any of you know of a better way of reordering layers in ImageView32, please let me know.

**EDIT**

So, please observe in the image bellow that the GUI is done, and working. I have the panels representing the layers, I can move them around (as you may see in the image I am dragging layer 'Elementul 0' and movin it up in the chain). 
[image]
And I repeat, my logic also works when I use temporary files for moving layers up or down in the order. One of the answers suggested that I should just use the Index property to change a layers position in the layers hierarchy, and I am saying that it cannot be done without at least adding new layers to the image. So this is not a double question. It is just a response to one of the answers I received.

Thank you

Comment: My guess is that one of the layers doesn't have a bitmap.

Comment: But like I said, if I do not change the order of the indexes of the layers, the saving works fine. The moment I send a layer to back... the error appears. So the layers are the same, just their order is changed when crash occurs

Comment: Oh, do not trust me, I might be wrong, but trust the debugger. Just step through your save procedure and SaveBmpAsPng and check for yourself.

Comment: In response to your edit. Layer orders can be changed by setting the `index` property of a layer.

Comment: Wow, if it was that easy... think like this: i have a panel displaying the layers, just like photoshop has. I drag and drop layers in that panel, and by moving them around, I want the same thing to happen to the actual graphic layers aswell. How do you do that using the indexes of the layers? I spent a lot of time thinking about it and I could not find a solution, other than removing the layers one by one from the image, and re-add them in the desired order.

Comment: The main problem with reordering indexes is : if you have 5 layers, and you the order is: 0,1,2,3,4. And you want the order to be 2,4,1,0,3... Then you might try setting ImgView.Layers[0].Index:=3, and so on... But right after you do your first asignment, all the indexes shift and you find yourself wondering what is the order now?

Comment: Anyway, a solution for reordering, might be to add a new empty layer, and use it as container for each changed layer, to store the existing one there before changing it, but I have not tested it yet. So far I tried the solution of reordering the panels by dropping the images in a temp folder, and re-adding them in the desired order. After I did this, the error described in my question vanished. So my problem is solved. I will post this as an answer. It might be helpfull to others.

Comment: It's amazing how strongly you are fighting the documented way of reordering layers. Do you still have a problem, and if so, is it related to reordering the layers, saving to file or reading from file?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a lot simpler than you might think. Working with layers comes natural:

**Send to back**

Set the layer's index to 0 or simply call `SendToBack`. *All layers previously before it will have their index increased by 1. All layers previously after it remain at the same position.*

**Send backward**

Decrease the layer's index by 1. *The layer previously before it will now come after it, thus has its index increased by one.*

**Send forward**

Increase the layer's index by 1. *The layer previously after it will now come before it, thus has its index decreased by one.*

**Send to front**

Set the layer's index to the number of layers minus 1. *The layers previously after it have their increased decreased by one.*

Hence there is absolutely no need to touch the bitmap, save to disk it to disk, or use any kind of temporary layers to change the order. In virtually every case, the right thing happens when you just set the index of the layer to the position (counting from 0, back to front) you want it to appear at. After moving a panel in your list, you could set the corresponding layer's index to the new index of the panel in the list. However, because the panel is ordered front to back and GR32 orders back to front, you need to translate the index of the panel to the desired index of the layer.

Here's an example how to do that with a `TListBox` and a `TButton`:

```
procedure TForm1.SendBackwardButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  LNewListBoxItemIndex: Integer;
begin
  // Calculate the new list index and make sure it's valid
  LNewListBoxItemIndex := Max(0, Min(ListBox1.ItemIndex + 1, ListBox1.Items.Count - 1));
  // Transform the current and new list indices and use them to move the layer
  ImgView321.Layers[ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 - ListBox1.ItemIndex].Index :=
    ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 - LNewListBoxItemIndex;
  // Move the list item
  ListBox1.Items.Move(ListBox1.ItemIndex, LNewListBoxItemIndex);
  // Preserve the selection (if applicable)
  ListBox1.ItemIndex := LNewListBoxItemIndex;
end;
```

You may also decide to fully synchronize the list with the layers. In that case you should associate each item (possibly `TPanel`) with a layer.

```
// Create layers from front to back
LLayer := TBitmapLayer.Create(ImgView321.Layers);
ListBox1.Items.AddObject('First layer', LLayer);    
// Could use LPanel := TPanel.Create(...); LPanel.Tag := Integer(Pointer(LLayer)) instead

LLayer := TBitmapLayer.Create(ImgView321.Layers);
ListBox1.Items.AddObject('Second layer', LLayer);   

// Now the list is correct but the layers are not in the right order.
// Use the code listed below whenever you need to synchronize the layers
// with the list. In theory it may be slow (O(n^2)) but practically it
// won't matter much assuming you won't have hundreds of layers.

// Don't update the screen every time we move a layer to get closer to the final result
ImgView321.BeginUpdate;
try
  for LIndex := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
    // Get the associated layer and make it the least visible of all processed so far
    TCustomLayer(ListBox1.Items.Objects[LIndex]).SendToBack;
    // Could use TCustomLayer(Pointer(SomePanel.Tag)).SendToBack instead
finally
  // Always do this not to have strange behavior after an error
  ImgView321.EndUpdate;
end;
// When it's done, update the screen
ImgView321.Changed;
```

Comment: Exactly what I have been trying to tell him, although earlier it wasn't clear that his panel/list goes in the opposite order. Plus one for explaining it better.

Answer (score 1):

By your description of how you changed the order of the layers, it is most likely the reason for your problem. Since you did not post that part of the code it can not be assessed with certainty.

Anyway, to rearrange the layers, you can use the `Index` property of `TCustomLayer` (of which `TBitmapLayer` is a descendant)

Comment: I already said I that found my problem (in the EDIT part of the question). Please post the code that you would use to reorder the layers using the index property of the layers (without adding new layers) and I will accept your answer

Comment: If you move (e.g. by drag and drop) panels on a 'masterpanel', you know in the `OnDragDrop` event which position the panel will have in relation to the other panels. Just assign the same index to the layer that the panel represents.

Comment: Did you ever tried this? I did. It messes the layers up. Consider the next scenario: you have 5 layers: 0,1,2,3,4. Each contains an image. Next you decide a new order for them, let's say 2,3,1,0,4. So Layer0 must contain the image of layer 2, then layer1 must contain the image from initial layer3 and so on. But after you set the contents of layer0, all the layers shift to the right so now, layer1 does not contain the image of layer1 but the image of initial layer0, and so on. It is extremely confusing, too confusing actually

Comment: But you said (ref to PhotoShop) the user would move the layer references(say ref0..ref4) in a panel or something (have you already decided what you will use?). You replicate the change in the order of the refs in the panel, to the layers. Step 1, user moves ref1 to become first in the panel. Ref1 sets the index of the layer it represents to its own position (0) and the layers are in order 1,0,2,3,4. Step 2, user moves ref2 and ref3 simultaneously to become the two first in the panel, ref2 sets its layers index to ref2s position (now 0) and  ref3 sets its layers index to ref3s position (now 1).

Comment: We have moved too far away from your original question, which was why you got an AV when saving layer images as .png files. Please start a new topic if needed for the rearranging of layers

Comment: I already have the GUI done. It works, except for the fact that when I rearrange (reorder) the layers, I use external temporary files. You said that it could be done just assigning new values to the layers indexes. And I was saying that you cant do that , Because you do not play with the values in an array of numbers... those indexes are linked to images, and when you change the index of an image, the index count stays the same, so the images behind those two indexes (source and destination) you play with, do not act like you expect.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to the problem is to NOT use a Bitmap32List as a temporary container for png layers when reordering layers, because something gets lost in the process.
So try other solution for reordering. My curent solution is to drop the layers as PNG files to the disk, then reload them from the disk in the desired order.
Another solution (untested yet) would be to create a number of new layers, equal to the number of existing layers, move actual layers there, then get them back one by one in the desired order, and then remove the extra layers.

Anyway. That was the question, and this is the answer so far